# How do I best optimize Picasso in a GridView?

Tags: android, picasso

I'm using Picasso (2.5.2) to load local `content://` images into a 3-column `GridView` via an adapter.

```
Picasso
    .with(mContext)
    .load(mCameraImages.getUris().get(position))
    .error(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
    .fit()
    .centerCrop()
    .into(view);
```

In my particular case, `mCameraImages` is a just a list of URIs, coming out of the local mediaStore.

I'm finding that when I load the `GridView`, Picasso always fetches the images from the disk (blue debug indicator) and not memory.

This is expected but I'd like to optimize the UX by loading thumbnails or images faster.

The "performance" is particular poor if you scroll the `GridView` down and have to wait for ~seconds for the disk fetch to complete.

What methods could I try to optimize Picasso loading so that local content can be displayed as quick as an app like [QuickPic](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.alensw.PicFolder&hl=en)?

[Here is my reduced adapter code](https://gist.github.com/mikeknoop/634d911baf9d314b0603) (it is very simple).

Comment: please show your adapter code

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide). It's supposed to be much faster and memory-efficient than Picasso. Also code is similar to Picasso, so you don't need much change in code.

**Sample Code:**

```
Glide.with(mContext)
    .load(mCameraImages.getUris().get(position))
    .error(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
    .centerCrop()
    .into(view);
```

Check this [Glide vs Picasso](http://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/get-to-know-glide-recommended-by-google/en) article to know detailed differences between the two.

Also check this [Improving Performance with the ViewHolder Pattern](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Using-an-ArrayAdapter-with-ListView#improving-performance-with-the-viewholder-pattern) to know about ViewHolder and implement that in your adapter to increase performance.

Comment: Thanks, will try. I've actually used the ViewHolder pattern too when experimenting with Fresco.The higher-order effect comes from loading from disk vs. memory when scrolling, though I suspected it might be due a backed up disk queue.

Comment: Just tried it, the default Glide GridView performance is a significant step up from Picasso without any tweaking.